# Register a .NET DLL with Activate Library mode

Tags: c#, iis, dll, registration, com+

I have a couple of .NET classes build to DLL files.
I use `regsvcs.exe` to register them to make them available in COM+ (VBscript) environments.

All those registered components are setup as `Activation => Server application`. This make this components runs in `dllhost.exe`.

As I run this in IIS with classic ASP I want to run it as `Library application`as this is 3times faster.

[image]

I did not find a option in `regsvcs.exe` how to set this on registration. So anyone knows how to set this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who seek this information, as I found it out myself already:

```
  COMAdminCatalog catalog = new COMAdminCatalog();
  COMAdminCatalogCollection applications = catalog.GetCollection("Applications");
  applications.Populate();
  foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject application in applications)
  {
    // list needs to be extended if more components needs registration
    if (application.Name == "your component name")
    {
      //application.set_Value("Authentication", 2);
      //application.set_Value("Identity", userName);
      //application.set_Value("Password", password);
      application.set_Value("Activation", "Inproc");
    }
  }
  applications.SaveChanges();
```